# How to disable WebGL in the Chrome browser on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webgl

How does one disable Google Chrome from using WebGL on a Mac (Mac OS X 10.6)?

(There currently appears to be some sort of security advisory regarding this component.)

Comment: I haven't heard of any security advisory. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Ditto. I've not heard of this either.

Comment: I highly doubt it's so serious u can't take the tiny risk of just running it normally untill it's patched

Comment: For those inquiring about the WebGL flaw, read the following: http://news.techworld.com/security/3286646/webgl-security-flaws-haunt-firefox-and-chrome/

Comment: Another good reason to disable WebGL is to conserve GPU resources for more important things like 3D rendering or 2D image editing. Why waste GPU resources on rendering web pages if there's something better they can be used for.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome lets you disable WebGL using the `about:flags` page.

Type `about:flags` into the URL bar and press return.

Find the `Disable WebGL` flag and enable it. Restart Chrome for changes to appear.

[image]

Comment: +1, much nicer solution than 'disable-webgl' which doesn't disable it all of the time.

Comment: Note that this switch is no longer there in current versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Well, seems that in the latest versions of Chrome this flag cannot be disabled from `about:flags`. In order to disable it:

- Close chrome (if running)
- Open the terminal.
- Type: `open -a "Google Chrome" --args  -disable-webgl`
- Profit!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how to do this in OS X, but you may be able to do so by running chrome from terminal with the "-disable-webgl" flag.